# can cljc single-file macro definitions to work with clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, macros, conditional-statements, clojurescript, reader

I have clojurescript successfully importing macros from other namespaces. But I wonder whether a single-file construction is/should be possible with clojure 1.7, such that a macro can be defined and used. What I have tried does not work, but maybe I've missed a detail someplace.

```
(ns cljc.core)

#?(:cljs
(enable-console-print!))

#?(:clj
(defmacro list-macro [x y]
  `(list ~x ~y)))

(defn foo [a]
  (println (list-macro a a)))

(foo :a)
```

This form fails with `list-macro` being undefined when compiling cljs; if I remove the :clj guard around list-macro, then defmacro is undefined within the cljs compilation. Is there a way?

Comment: No. ClojureScript macros are still Clojure. They do their work compile time - when ClojureScript code is compiled to JavaScript. So they need to be compiled (from Clojure to JVM) first, before any ClojureScript compilation take place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is a way for a single file construction.

```
(ns cljc.core
  #?(:cljs (:require-macros [cljc.core :refer [list-macro]])))

#?(:clj
(defmacro list-macro [x y]
;; ...
```

Assumedly one of the next CLJS compiler versions will do the import automatically.

Comment: i think that the author wants to write `defmacro`, not require

Comment: Yes. But he needs to write `:require-macros` to use the macro in ClojureScript. This is the answer to what he asked for.

Comment: Clever way to force CLJ compilation first along the way! Hopefully it will indeed one day work automatically, at least when in a cljc file.